# Reset Safari from command line

Tags: safari

I accidentally navigated to one of those sites that pops up a dialog telling me that my computer is infected. Upon clicking the OK button, that dialog reappears, ad infinitum.

I cannot close the tab or otherwise interact with Safari while the dialog is up. No matter how many times I Quit or Force Quit (and no matter how many times I tell Safari "Do Not Re-open Windows") the previously-open set of tabs always reopens and this dialog pops to the fore.

How can I delete the state of things while Safari is closed?

Comment: Go to Macintosh HD / Users / YOU / Library / Cache / com.apple.Safari / and delete that folder (com.apple.Safari).

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: hmm...? then follow this instructions http://seanscus.blogspot.com/2012/08/completely-reset-safari.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From http://seanscus.blogspot.com/2012/08/completely-reset-safari.html

Open a terminal and enter the following commands to fully wipe out all of your old Safari settings:

`` mv ~/Library/Safari ~/Desktop/Safari-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Apple\ -\ Safari\ -\ Safari\ Extensions\ Gallery; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.WebKit.PluginProcess; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/Apple\ -\ Safari\ -\ Safari\ Extensions\ Gallery; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.LSSharedFileList.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.RSS.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.WebFoundation.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.WebKit.PluginHost.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.WebKit.PluginProcess.plist; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/PubSub/Database; \
rm -Rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState ``

Comment: Excellent. Just what you need.

Comment: does not seem to work on Safari 8

Comment: Got rid that annoying systemfailure.xyz process on Safari 9.

Answer (score 16):

Oh, my! Just press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when launching Safari from the dock.

But you have got in answers above exactly what you have asked for)

Comment: Even now under Yosemite?

Comment: Why don't you try?)

Comment: Because I'm logged in and working and I'm afraid it would work. Do you have the time by chance?

Comment: It didn't work, I'm still logged in.

Comment: Yes, it is working in Yosemite. Anyway there is always Reopen All Windows from Last Session under History menu to get all your windows restored.

Comment: Caveat is you have to click on Safari icon in the dock for it to work.

Comment: That's what I'm doing.

Comment: I have tried all possible scenarios (or so I think) running from spotlight shift start slow-mo, running from Applications is the same. Holding Shift while clicking on Safari icon in the dock (of closed browser) is just open one new window with favourites like in my Preferences stated

Comment: It is actually documented feature since Safari 5 and Lion when Resume was introduced — http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5364

Comment: That's the only thing that worked in my case. 

Comment: This fixed it for me, no need for command-line chicanery.  FWIW I was holding `shift` while clicking on the Launchpad icon since I don't have it in the dock.

Comment: works for Catalina

Comment: wau !!!  it was freezing while opening one tab from last session ... I could not find this simple solution....

Answer (score 7):

Disconnect your computer from the internet (disable wlan)
Then delete browser history (Safari/Preferences/Privacy: remove all website data)

Answer (score 3):

I created a script, `DeleteSafariTabs.command`, and made it executable so I can just double-click the script.

This method leaves your history and bookmarks intact, and reliably deletes the previously open tabs.

```
# Most apple apps (if not all) have a file inside of
# ~/Saved Application State/ so by deleting that we
# get rid of the state of open windows Safari is using.
rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState

# There is also some information about the previous
# session here so we delete this as well.
rm ~/Library/Safari/LastSession.plist
```

You can make the file executable by typing in `chmod +x`, pressing the space bar, and dragging in `DeleteSafariTabs.command` from Finder into the Terminal window.

Comment: Might be worth trying to use formatting on those two commands to make it clearer that it is code.

Answer (score 1):

Quit Safari>Click on GO in finder> go to Folder> ~/Library/> rename folder named Safari to Safari1.

Reopen Safari, it will start new and a new Safari Folder will be created in Library.

Bring back some files like Bookmark etc one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are really looking for an easy answer, disconnect from local network (Wifi/ ethernet).  Open Safari and then force quit it to loose the cache.  Then restart safari (it'll try to connect to the suspicious phishing pages but has no cached version. Go to menu -> safari -> reset safari and hit okay on popup to delete all history/ cache/ cookies etc

Answer (score 1):

@Iskra 's answer nails it, The below steps works even there's no Safari in the dock.

1 - Open terminal

2 - Issue `killall Safari`

3 - Go to the list of apps (Four fingers swipe-inwards)

4 - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click Safari

Answer (score 0):

Safari stores its window state in `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState`. If you close Safari, then rename that folder, the next time you open Safari it'll open with a blank slate.

Alternatively, you could temporarily disable the saved state feature across the board by going into the General pane of System Preferences and ticking the "Close windows when quitting an appellation" checkbox. If you open Safari after doing that, it'll also open with a blank slate. Remember to untick it afterward if you want to turn the saved state feature back on.

Comment: This is no longer true in Yosemite, there's no such folder for me. Apple changes this sort of thing on a per-build basis so I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: They don't change it. That folder has been the same for quite a few OS releases. However I did screw up the path in my answer originally; that's why you wouldn't have found it. I've fixed the path in my answer now. If you check for the amended path you should find it now.

Comment: Aye, I can find it now. But my warning still stands, as Apple does in fact change the location of settings all the time.

Answer (score 0):

To reset a highjacked Safari:

- Click Go
- select Go to folder
- type in: ~/Library/Cookies
- hit Go
- Send all the frenkin cookies to the
  trash
- Close folder
- Launch Safari
- You are Welcome!!!

Pass it on

Answer (score 0):

I just typed google website on a word sheet, clicked on the link then go to preferences and change the home page back.

Answer (score 0):

I find it most useful to create a `.bash_alias` file and add it to your `.bash_profile`.

Add this alias to `.bash_alias` and any other useful command line scripts.

```
alias resetsafari='rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState; rm ~/Library/Safari/LastSession.plist
```

You will need to `source .bash_profile` again to refresh the aliases.

In the event you forget your saved aliases, just type `alias` into Terminal to see all current aliases.
(This is a modification of the code someone posted above, modified into an alias form.)